Map through an array - toggle first option, second to false
I want to write a function where if isActive.id === 'singlesided' then its status is toggled and at the same time 'doublesided' is set to false.
Idea is that singleSided and soubleSided cannot be true at the same time.
Managed to toggle the first option, but cannot find a way to set second to false...
setup.store.ts:
    const initialState: LightboxState = {
          isActive: [
           { id: 'singleSided', status: false },
           { id: 'doubleSided', status: false },
           { id: 'illuminated', status: false },
           { id: 'notIlluminated', status: false },
           { id: 'standing', status: false },
           { id: 'hanging', status: false },
      ],
}

export const LightboxStore = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },
  withState(initialState),
  withMethods((store) => ({
    activeStatus(statusId: string, statusFalse: string): void {
      patchState(store, {
        isActive: store.isActive().map((isActiveId) => {
          if (isActiveId.id === statusId) {
            return { ...isActiveId, status: !isActiveId.status };
          }
          return isActiveId;
        }),
      });
    },
  }))
);

I want to run it through a button click as:
store.activeStatus('singleSided', 'doubleSided')

where the first option is toggled(true/false) and second is set to false.

To properly use .map(), you should return a new entry for each object in the original state array. Set the status to false for each element that doesn't have the target matching id.

That's not exactly what I wanted. I do not want to set false to all the rest, but to one option that was passed from the function.
I think I solved the problem by adding another if statement that checks if the second option was passed and sets it to false.
